# Intercept object attribute access in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to intercept access attribute to object which previously has not been set in JavaScript. I wonder if it's possible?

The equivalent in Python is the `__getattr__` built-in method:

```
class P(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return name

p = P()
x = p.x
```

p.x doesn't previously exist, but `__getattr__` intercept access to a member variable that has not previously been created. Anything similar in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to do this with [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). Example from MDN:

```
var handler = {
    get: function(target, name){
        return name in target?
            target[name] :
            37;
    }
};

var p = new Proxy({}, handler);
p.a = 1;
p.b = undefined;

console.log(p.a, p.b); // 1, undefined
console.log('c' in p, p.c); // false, 37
```

However, [currently browser support is basically non-existent](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#Proxy) and polyfilling this is not really possible.

Comment: Thanks. What's the netiquette in duplicated question here? Should I delete it or leave it as it is?

Comment: Leave it. It's like a "guidepost" to the duplicate.

Comment: I guess it could be useful. I used with the word "intercept" instead of "catch" or "dynamic setter", so it could be helpful for people who think like I did.